# How can I get the SIM type (eSIM/Old SIM) on Android programatically?

Tags: android, linux, modem, cellular-network

I want to detect the SIM type from an Android app. Whether it's an eSIM (embedded SIM) or not.

I'm playing with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/euicc/EuiccManager. But no success yet!

Answer (score 1):

Android has an API to detect embedded SIM https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo#isEmbedded().

Comment: It just shows the current subscription is ESIM or not. Not if the device supports ESIM